# QGIS export to DXF scale issue

Tags: qgis, polygon, dxf, autocad, dwg

I'm trying to make a Nolli map. I was able to convert all the buildings in my chosen area to black vectors and export them to DXF, but when I open the resulting DXF file, the drawing is not scaled down equally along the x and y directions, so it appears squished.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It is possible that the problem you are having is related to the CRS (Coordinate Reference System) settings. When loading the DXF in QGIS it is necessary to assign a CRS according to the original CRS captured vectors. From the menu Layer -> Layer Properties -> Source you can access to this settings